# Background, local update tasks in iOS7

Tags: background, ios7

I have a timer related app,that lets the user set timer to different objects.

**What I am doing right now -**
Right now.I am scheduling a local notification when the timer gets to it's end, and then when the user gets the notification, he needs to open the app so it could process the changes related to this timer.

**What I want to achieve  -**

I have looked on the new iOS7 background modes but could not determine if I can use that to perform those updates to the core data, without opening the app.

So the flow will be:

1. a timer is coming to it's end.
2. The user gets a local notification where he needs to permit the operation.
3. Get the user answer and perform the update while the app is still in the background.

Is that possible with the new API ? Or is it limited to data fetches only ?

Comment: Timers are not useful in ios7 background apps. system will stop timer after 3 min.

Answer (score 0):

If you are you are using Push Notification Using ios 7 new background fetcher api is useful,

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))handler
{
}
```

When a push notification arrives, the system displays the notification
to the user and launches the app in the background (if needed)so that it can call this method. Use this method
to download any data related and store to core data to the push notification. When your method is done, call the block in the handler
parameter.